# how to disable launch of default emulator on 'react-native run-android'?

Tags: adb, react-native

I don't want to run emulator at all. But `'react-native run-android'` starts an emulator even though I have a physical device already connected ('adb devices' command shows it) and then 'react-native run-android' command fails with error `'error: more than one device/emulator'`

```
info JS server already running.
'C:\Users\Wings' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
info Launching emulator...
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to delete all emulators in ADB to disable automatic launch of emulators but I think that shouldn't be the perfect solution as I will have to recreate AVDs when I need to.